# Excel - Convert dates to numbers confusion

Tags: excel

I have following error data:

for example instead of value 1.65, date January 65 is writen

[image]

When I try to converter it with the Cell formater to a decimaml number I get this

[image]

Why I am not geting what I expect?

Comment: You have to format cells before writing data. When excel detects any number as date, then it will convert date value (value of date as number) when you reformat the cell as number.

Comment: Looking at your image, looks like your decimal separator **is not** the dot because numbers are right aligned by default, so Excel is not reading data as numbers but strings. I don't know how you get this but try first to make Excel to understand everything properly  and maybe you'll get rid of the issue with `Jän.74`